# Adding lines perpendicular in the plane to a Mobius Band

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to draw line pointing perpendicular from the centre line in this diagram along the surface to show that the Mobius Band is non-orientable, I've tried manually plotting lines along the path but I seem to be having trouble placing them accurately. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps, external}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
view={40}{40}
]
\addplot3 [
mesh, shader=faceted interp,
point meta=x,
colormap/blackwhite,
samples=100,
samples y=5,
z buffer=sort,
domain=0:360,
y domain=-0.5:0.5
] (
{(1+0.5*y*cos(x/2)))*cos(x)},
{(1+0.5*y*cos(x/2)))*sin(x)},
{0.5*y*sin(x/2)});

\addplot3 [
samples=50,
domain=-145:180,
samples y=0,
thick
] (
{cos(x)},
{sin(x)},
{0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is how the Mobius band looks like

[image]

Comment: In addition to what you have given, could you also post a picture, where you show what you have, and what you need? Moreover, what is a Mobius band?

Comment: This is what a Mobius Band/strip looks like, as for including a picture I'm not sure how to go about doing that??https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mobius+band&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf9-2fl5rTAhVIJcAKHXzmCTYQ_AUIBigB&biw=1920&bih=974#imgrc=htKAVeKehZVgjM:

Comment: I have added your Mobius band, could you make necessary edits using some software, and show a schematic of what you want here?

Comment: Sorry I'm very limited in my capabilities with the required software, essentially what I'm after is this but with simple back arrows and only along a central line (that I have in bold) https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mobius+band+not+orientable&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-krCanZrTAhXsJsAKHZq5CzkQ_AUIBygC&biw=1920&bih=974#imgrc=mTCQ6ZipA0KTMM:

Comment: Welcome! Pointing to a google image search is not helpful. Which image are you trying to direct us to? I probably don't even get the same results you do and, even if I do, I have no way of knowing which image you want people to look at. Can you direct us to a specific image?

Answer (score 9):

Something like this?

[image: Möbius strip with arrows]

Obviously, you will need to adjust it in light of whatever you actually want. However, you should be able to do that provided you want something like what I understand the general idea of your question to be.

The basic idea is to use `markings` to place nodes at intervals. Each node is rotated through 90 degrees. This isn't quite right, because it is happening in 2D rather than 3D. But it may be good enough for purposes of illustration.

The nodes are from `shapes.arrows` with empty content and a `text height` of `0pt` so that they look, essentially, like lines with arrows at the end.

You could alternatively mark with arrow tips (e.g. from `arrows.meta`). This works well, but I couldn't figure out any way to add the tip to a line. Indeed, I couldn't figure out how to draw a line in the right place at all. (I don't know how to specify a relative coordinate with `axis cs`.)

You can, however, customise the arrow nodes further as desired. See the `shapes.arrows` library documentation in the Ti*k*Z manual for details.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps, external}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      hide axis,
      view={40}{40}
    ]
    \addplot3
    [
      mesh, shader=faceted interp,
      point meta=x,
      colormap/blackwhite,
      samples=100,
      samples y=5,
      z buffer=sort,
      domain=0:360,
      y domain=-0.5:0.5,
    ]
    (%
      {(1+0.5*y*cos(x/2)))*cos(x)},
      {(1+0.5*y*cos(x/2)))*sin(x)},
      {0.5*y*sin(x/2)}
    );
    \addplot3
    [
      samples=50,
      domain=-145:180,
      samples y=0,
      thick,
      postaction={decorate},
      decoration={% pgfplots manual 355-356
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 2.5mm with
        {
          \node [single arrow, transform shape, rotate=-90, fill, draw, inner sep=0pt, single arrow head extend=1pt, text width=2.5mm, text height=0pt, anchor=west, line width=.4pt, ] {};
        },
      },
    ]
    (%
      {cos(x)},
      {sin(x)},
      {0}%
    );
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```